# How to design custom cell row wise individually in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, customization, custom-cell

Could any one help me? Am working on expanding cell for the past one week Finally i can able to add sub menu in it. I designed two custom cells and using plist i added menu and sub menu to that. It is working well i added menu and sub menu. Now my problem is i want to add image and button to row 1,2,4,6 only using indexpath.row i assigned but this code assigning image and button to all rows But i only want to add to row 1,2,4,6 only ho i can do this pls some one help me???

```
interface MyHomeView ()
{

    NSMutableArray *LeftPaneList;
    NSArray *datalist;

}
@property (assign)BOOL isOpen;
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSIndexPath *selectIndex;
@end

  - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSString *path  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"LeftPaneMenuList" ofType:@"plist"];
    LeftPaneList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];



    self.isOpen=NO;

 }


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [LeftPaneList count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (self.isOpen) {
        if (self.selectIndex.section == section) {
            return [[[LeftPaneList objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"SubMenu"] count]+1;;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{




    if (self.isOpen&&self.selectIndex.section == indexPath.section&&indexPath.row!=0) {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyHomeViewCell2";
        MyHomeViewCell2 *cell = (MyHomeViewCell2*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        NSArray *list = [[LeftPaneList objectAtIndex:self.selectIndex.section] objectForKey:@"SubMenu"];
        cell.name.text = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];



        return cell;


   }

    else
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyHomeViewCell";
       MyHomeViewCell *cell = (MyHomeViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        cell.tag=indexPath.row;


        NSString *name = [[LeftPaneList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"MenuName"];

cell.MyHomeMenuLabel.text = name;
        return cell;




}
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        if ([indexPath isEqual:self.selectIndex]) {
            self.isOpen = NO;
            [self didSelectCellRowFirstDo:NO nextDo:NO];
            self.selectIndex = nil;

        }else
        {
            if (!self.selectIndex) {
                self.selectIndex = indexPath;
                [self didSelectCellRowFirstDo:YES nextDo:NO];

            }else
            {

                [self didSelectCellRowFirstDo:NO nextDo:YES];
            }
        }

    }


    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}


- (void)didSelectCellRowFirstDo:(BOOL)firstDoInsert nextDo:(BOOL)nextDoInsert
{
    self.isOpen = firstDoInsert;


    [self.MyHomeTableView beginUpdates];

    int section = self.selectIndex.section;
    int contentCount = [[[LeftPaneList objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"SubMenu"] count];
    NSMutableArray* rowToInsert = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSUInteger i = 1; i < contentCount + 1; i++) {
        NSIndexPath* indexPathToInsert = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section];




        [rowToInsert addObject:indexPathToInsert];
    }

    if (firstDoInsert)
    {   [self.MyHomeTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:rowToInsert withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.MyHomeTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:rowToInsert withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }



    [self.MyHomeTableView endUpdates];
    if (nextDoInsert) {
        self.isOpen = YES;
        self.selectIndex = [self.MyHomeTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        [self didSelectCellRowFirstDo:YES nextDo:NO];
    }
    if (self.isOpen) [self.MyHomeTableView scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 52;
}
```

This is the original o/p![image]

But i want o/p like this[image]

some one help me??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to specify `IndexPath.section` First then you can check with `IndexPath.row` like Bellow Example:-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if(indexPath.section==0)
    {
        if(indexPath.row==0)
        {

           cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellWithButton" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
        else if(indexPath.row==2)
        {
          cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellWithButton" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        }
        else if(indexPath.row==2)
        {
          cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellWithButton" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        }
        else if(indexPath.row==4)
        {
          cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellWithButton" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        }
        else if(indexPath.row==6)
        {

          cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellWithButton" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
        else
       {
         cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
       }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Th easy way to do this, is to set up 2 different dynamic prototype cells in the storyboard, each with its own identifier. In cellForRowAtIndexPath: dequeue the correct type of cell based on the indexPath.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if (indexPath.row = 1 || indexPath.row = 2 || indexPath.row = 4 || indexPath.row = 6){
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellWithButton" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }else{
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method, it will just give cell at index path 2, 4, 6 etc to some other cell in tableView. Instead use array to store your cell and then retrieve it from array. And then you can use indexpath.row

Comment: i Stored cell in array and used indexpath.row but it is not working